# Why am I using LLVM?

Tags: terminal, virtualbox

I was testing the 14.04 release of Ubuntu on VirtualBox, and later, after having gotten a pretty good idea of the changes, removed VirtualBox from my computer. However, when I ran the command 'python' in the terminal... this is what I found:

[image]

Why is it that LLVM is being used in terminal?

Comment: what does `which python` returns ?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 3):

When you launch python interactively, it prints its version, and the name and version of the compiler that was used to compile it.

In this case, Apple compiled the python executables using clang-500.0.68 (masquerading itself as GCC 4.2.1).

Comment: Why exactly? I've never seen it do that before...

Comment: Apple uses clang/LLVM combo as their default compiler for anything they distribute. Python is among those applications. For compatibility reasons (I think) they provide gcc and g++ commands still, however they both use clang.

Comment: I can't say that I've ever seen it before either. Then again, I probably just never paid enough attention. :) My linux boxes all do the same, except they list "gcc" and "linux" instead of "clang" and "darwin" (for obvious reasons).